# Javascript issues using the Google geocoding api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, scope

I'm working on a simple application that takes in two location parameters and calculates the distance between the two.  I'm using the Google geocoding api and I think the issue is something simple with Javascript.  I new to it though, and I can't seem to figure out how to get my function to return the correct object.  I think it is an issue with scope, and I can't seem to hack it out.

I see what you were saying about is being asynchronous, but I'm not sure how to handle two different sets of coordinates.

Here is my entire JS file:

```
function getCoordinates (address1, address2, callback) {
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var coordinates;
  geocoder.geocode({ address: address1}, function (results, status) {
    obj = results[0].geometry.location;
    coordinates.push(obj.k, obj.B);
  })
  geocoder.geocode({ address: address2}, function (results, status) {
    obj = results[0].geometry.location;
    coordinates.push(obj.k, obj.B);
  })
  callback(coordinates);
}


function distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
  var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
  var dLat = (lat2 - lat1) * Math.PI / 180;
  var dLon = (lon2 - lon1) * Math.PI / 180;
  var a = 
    0.5 - Math.cos(dLat)/2 + 
    Math.cos(lat1 * Math.PI / 180) * Math.cos(lat2 * Math.PI / 180) * 
    (1 - Math.cos(dLon))/2;

  return R * 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));
}

function calculateDistance(coordinates){
  return distance(coordinates[0] coordinates[1], coordinates[2], coordinates[3]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the request is asynchronous you can't return from it, response is not yet available when you return it. Instead you can use callback function to be invoked once data has come from server:

```
function getCoordinates(address, callback) {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({address: address}, function(results, status) {
        var obj = results[0].geometry.location;
        callback([obj.k, obj.B]);
    });
}
```

And the usage is:

```
getCoordinates(address, function(coordinates) {
    console.log(coordinates);
});
```

Also don't forget to declare variables with `var` keyword. Without it variable becomes global which can lead to unpredictable issues.

Comment: Ok so that make sense, but I'm having trouble getting it to work with two sets of coordinates. My code at this point is: